# Kafka/PubSub connector: Example pipeline: ERROR Task Converting byte[], Unrecognized token, was expecting ('true', 'false' or 'null')

Tags: command-line, apache-kafka, google-cloud-pubsub

I am using `kafka_2.11-0.10.2.1` and the pubsub connector provided by google [here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/pubsub/tree/master/kafka-connector). All I care to do is push data from a Kafka Topic to a PubSub one using a standalone connector. I followed all steps as I should have:

1. Produced the `cps-kafka-connector.jar`
2. Added the `cps-sink-connector.properties` file in kafka's `config` directory. The file looks like this:

> ```
> name=CPSConnector
> connector.class=com.google.pubsub.kafka.sink.CloudPubSubSinkConnector
> tasks.max=10
> topics=kafka_topic
> cps.topic=pubsub_topic
> cps.project=my_gcp_project_12345
> ```

3. I made sure I am not enabling any converters in `connect-standalone.properties`:

> ```
> key.converter.schemas.enable=false
> value.converter.schemas.enable=false
> ```

4. I created a topic `kafka_topic` and sent some messages as follows:

> ```
> $ bin/kafka-console-producer.sh --broker-list localhost:9092 --topic kafka_topic
> $ hello streams
> $ kafka streams rock
> ```

5. I ran the connector as follows:

> ```
> $ bin/connect-standalone.sh config/connect-standalone.properties config/cps-sink-connector.properties
> ```

and the intention is to the run:

> ```
> $ gcloud beta pubsub subscriptions pull subscription_to_pubsub_topic
> ```

to collect those messages. However, the following errors occur and I cannot get my head around them. Any thoughts? Am I using the wrong input? What would be the correct sample input?

```
    [2017-05-04 17:34:40,898] INFO Discovered coordinator 10.33.19.146:9092 (id: 2147483647 rack: null) for group connect-CPSConnector. (org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator:586)
  [2017-05-04 17:34:40,899] INFO Revoking previously assigned partitions [] for group connect-CPSConnector (org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator:397)
  [2017-05-04 17:34:40,900] INFO (Re-)joining group connect-CPSConnector (org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator:420)
  [2017-05-04 17:34:40,936] ERROR Task CPSConnector-4 threw an uncaught and unrecoverable exception (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask:141)
  org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.DataException: Converting byte[] to Kafka Connect data failed due to serialization error:
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter.toConnectData(JsonConverter.java:305)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.convertMessages(WorkerSinkTask.java:401)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.poll(WorkerSinkTask.java:249)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.iteration(WorkerSinkTask.java:179)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.execute(WorkerSinkTask.java:148)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.doRun(WorkerTask.java:139)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.run(WorkerTask.java:182)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
  Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unrecognized token 'hello': was expecting ('true', 'false' or 'null')
   at [Source: [B@3c06c37d; line: 1, column: 11]
  Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unrecognized token 'hello': was expecting ('true', 'false' or 'null')
   at [Source: [B@3c06c37d; line: 1, column: 11]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser._constructError(JsonParser.java:1702)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.base.ParserMinimalBase._reportError(ParserMinimalBase.java:558)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.UTF8StreamJsonParser._reportInvalidToken(UTF8StreamJsonParser.java:3524)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.UTF8StreamJsonParser._handleUnexpectedValue(UTF8StreamJsonParser.java:2686)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.UTF8StreamJsonParser._nextTokenNotInObject(UTF8StreamJsonParser.java:878)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.UTF8StreamJsonParser.nextToken(UTF8StreamJsonParser.java:772)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._initForReading(ObjectMapper.java:3834)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:3783)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readTree(ObjectMapper.java:2404)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonDeserializer.deserialize(JsonDeserializer.java:50)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter.toConnectData(JsonConverter.java:303)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.convertMessages(WorkerSinkTask.java:401)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.poll(WorkerSinkTask.java:249)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.iteration(WorkerSinkTask.java:179)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.execute(WorkerSinkTask.java:148)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.doRun(WorkerTask.java:139)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.run(WorkerTask.java:182)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
  [2017-05-04 17:34:40,941] ERROR Task is being killed and will not recover until manually restarted (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask:142)
  [2017-05-04 17:34:43,837] INFO Revoking previously assigned partitions [] for group connect-CPSConnector (org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator:397)
  [2017-05-04 17:34:43,838] INFO (Re-)joining group connect-CPSConnector (org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator:420)
  [2017-05-04 17:34:43,846] INFO Successfully joined group connect-CPSConnector with generation 3 (org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator:388)
  [2017-05-04 17:34:43,846] INFO Successfully joined group connect-CPSConnector with generation 3 (org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator:388)
  [2017-05-04 17:34:43,847] INFO Setting newly assigned partitions [] for group connect-CPSConnector (org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator:256)
  [2017-05-04 17:34:43,847] INFO Successfully joined group connect-CPSConnector with generation 3 (org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator:388)
  [2017-05-04 17:34:43,848] INFO Setting newly assigned partitions [] for group connect-CPSConnector (org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator:256)
  [2017-05-04 17:34:43,850] INFO Successfully joined group connect-CPSConnector with generation 3 (org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator:388)
  [2017-05-04 17:34:43,851] INFO Successfully joined group connect-CPSConnector with generation 3 (org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator:388)
  [2017-05-04 17:34:43,851] INFO Successfully joined group connect-CPSConnector with generation 3 (org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator:388)
  [2017-05-04 17:34:43,851] INFO Successfully joined group connect-CPSConnector with generation 3 (org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator:388)
  [2017-05-04 17:34:43,853] INFO Setting newly assigned partitions [] for group connect-CPSConnector (org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator:256)
  [2017-05-04 17:34:43,846] INFO Successfully joined group connect-CPSConnector with generation 3 (org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator:388)
  [2017-05-04 17:34:43,851] INFO Setting newly assigned partitions [test8-0] for group connect-CPSConnector (org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator:256)
  [2017-05-04 17:34:43,851] INFO Setting newly assigned partitions [] for group connect-CPSConnector (org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator:256)
  [2017-05-04 17:34:43,851] INFO Setting newly assigned partitions [] for group connect-CPSConnector (org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator:256)
  [2017-05-04 17:34:43,850] INFO Successfully joined group connect-CPSConnector with generation 3 (org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator:388)
  [2017-05-04 17:34:43,856] INFO Setting newly assigned partitions [] for group connect-CPSConnector (org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator:256)
  [2017-05-04 17:34:43,846] INFO Setting newly assigned partitions [] for group connect-CPSConnector (org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator:256)
  [2017-05-04 17:34:43,854] INFO Setting newly assigned partitions [] for group connect-CPSConnector (org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator:256)
  [2017-05-04 17:34:43,862] ERROR Task CPSConnector-0 threw an uncaught and unrecoverable exception (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask:141)
  org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.DataException: Converting byte[] to Kafka Connect data failed due to serialization error:
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter.toConnectData(JsonConverter.java:305)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.convertMessages(WorkerSinkTask.java:401)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.poll(WorkerSinkTask.java:249)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.iteration(WorkerSinkTask.java:179)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.execute(WorkerSinkTask.java:148)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.doRun(WorkerTask.java:139)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.run(WorkerTask.java:182)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
  Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unrecognized token 'hello': was expecting ('true', 'false' or 'null')
   at [Source: [B@32a6e3e6; line: 1, column: 11]
  Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unrecognized token 'hello': was expecting ('true', 'false' or 'null')
   at [Source: [B@32a6e3e6; line: 1, column: 11]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser._constructError(JsonParser.java:1702)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.base.ParserMinimalBase._reportError(ParserMinimalBase.java:558)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.UTF8StreamJsonParser._reportInvalidToken(UTF8StreamJsonParser.java:3524)
    ...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These lines in `connect-standalone.properties` do not disable converters:

```
key.converter.schemas.enable=false
value.converter.schemas.enable=false
```

They disable including a schema with certain converters such as the JSON converter. The lines you are interested in are:

```
key.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
value.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
```

The `key.converter` and `value.converter` fields indicate the format of the data in the Kafka messages' key and value, respectively. Since you are publishing messages that are not valid JSON, you are seeing this error. You will want to set these converters to the StringConverter:

```
key.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter 
value.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter
```

Comment: Thanks @Kamal Aboul-Hosn. This seems to work, however now I am getting a new error so I can't check if your suggestion solved everything. The error I am getting is `Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Jetty ALPN/NPN has not been properly configured.` Any ideas on how I can fix this? Would like to avoind posting a new question for it if it is not necessary. Thanks.

Comment: I ended up posting another question. Would appreciate your input: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43793486/kafka-pubsub-connector-jetty-alpn-npn-has-not-been-properly-configured

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It solved my problem of redis sink connector